# How to get specific values from a table in R?

Tags: r, row, rows, specifications

How do I get the values to show when I want to get them from a table?
I have the following dataset:

```
ORF      Name      G1      G1.Bkg      R1      R1.Bkg

007C     ERG11    8432      2404      7896      1155

218C     PYC2    11509      2148      12144     1074

051W     FUN43    5865      2422      4478

053W      NA      6762      2107      6343      1020
```

I need to find G1 and R1 for some specific names.
Im using `data[(data$Name="FUN43"), c(2,3,5)]` to get the values from G1 and R1 for FUN43.
The commandline returns the following:

```
    Name    G1    R1
NA  <NA>    NA    NA
```

Is there any way to show the values instead of getting `NA`?

Comment: please post the `dput(dataset)` of your dataset.

Comment: Try using `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

```
data[which(data$Name == "FUN43"),c(2,3,5)]
```